# condition not executing while using <s:if > tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

**In the following code the label is always contract.alerts.column.emailtext.clearcneRequested even if condition is true.**
 **please let me know if Im missing anything in the code** 
 Also I need to print the value that comes in key. how can I do that ?

```
<div  id="alertPopUpDiv" style="display: none;"  >
        <table id="tableListingAlerts" width="1150px">
                <thead>


                        <s:if test="%{key == ' Conflicts Cleared'}"> 
                            <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.conflictsCleared')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                        </s:if>
                        <s:else>
                            <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.clearcneRequested')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                        </s:else>

                </thead>
                <tbody id="mainAlertTBody" > 
                </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

I have also tried using

```
<c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${key == 'Conflicts Cleared'}"> 
                                <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.conflictsCleared')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                            </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.clearcneRequested')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                        </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

still only contract.alerts.column.emailtext.lrccclearcneRequested gets printed

Comment: what is this tag `<s:if>` .. Why dont you use `jstl` c:if tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `key` may be null. Print the key before you enter the `<c:choose>` tag . your syntax seems to be correct.

```
<c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${key == 'Conflicts Cleared'}"> 
                                <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.conflictsCleared')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                            </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <tr><th align='center'  colspan='9'><b><label for="name-prefix"><s:property value="%{getLabel('contract.alerts.column.emailtext.clearcneRequested')}" /></label></b></th></tr>
                        </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

Comment: please show me pirnt the key value before <c:choose tag

Comment: simple print the key using EL `${key}`